How do I go about adding a sinusoidal value to Layer Weight facing value?
I've been trying to recreate a shading style from an drawing someone made, and I feel like I'm about 90% there. Just can't seem to visualize what I need to do next.
The intended result:

Current Progress:

As you can see, I've gotten most of it down, I just can't quite nail down what I need to do in order to fully recreate it. I'm just unsure of what I have to do in order to get that rounded effect added to it. I thought about adding, say a rectified sine wave to the layer weight value, but I don't quite know how to do that without it just being added radially to the overall object.
I'm extremely new to using shaders for anything other than a basic cel shader in EEVEE. See my attached node tree:

Any ideas on how I would accomplish this?
Blendshare File:


Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/, to reproduce your "Current Progress" figure ?

.blend file added!
